# Blender did not run and shows some error

Tags: drivers, opengl

[image]

When I tried to run the blender it shows this I don't know how to solve this as I am new to coding. Anybody help me with that??

Comment: Your GPU doesn't seem to fulfill the [minimum requirements](https://www.blender.org/download/requirements/) for running Blender 2.8x. If your GPU is supported, then this could also be caused by an old graphics driver and you should try to update it.

Comment: but when I open it in windows it works perfectly but didn't run in ubuntu terminal and showing this errors.